# Why won't Bootstrap let me set margins on dropdowns in ASP.NET MVC page?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having some issues with Bootstrap/CSS in my ASP.NET MVC app. I've got a ´form-group´ with a label to the left and a vertical stack of dropdowns to the right.

I've now set it up the way I want it except for the margins. Currently there are none. It seems like the margins that I'm giving are not effective. I've pretty much took this from a video tutorial on YouTube. I don't understand why this doesn't work.

I've tried all kind of things, `mb-4`, `mt-4`, `my-4`, ...

What am I doing wrong here? I've checked I use bootstrap v3.3.7.

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedTags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", id = "lblSelectedTags" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tag1, Model.AvailableTags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control mb-4", id = "ddlTag1" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tag2, Model.AvailableTags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control mb-4", id = "ddlTag2" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tag3, Model.AvailableTags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control mb-4", id = "ddlTag3" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FriendlyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", id = "lblFriendlyName" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FriendlyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "edrFriendlyName" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FriendlyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: bootstrap spacing works only in version 4+:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7, I've tagged both because there only was bootstrap-4 and twitter-bootstrap-3 available, I'm a little confused about this, Are there significant differences? I've retagged it.

Comment: Yes between 3 and 4 there are  significant differences:https://blog.templatetoaster.com/bootstrap-3-vs-bootstrap-4-migrate-differences/

Comment: you mean like `class = "form-control margin-bottom-lg-4"` (sorry really a newbie to CSS)

Comment: OK, I understand, they've renamed it in Bootstrap 4. Just retried it with the `margin-bottom`, still the same. I've wrapped it up into divs, but still the same.

Comment: can you post working code maybe in fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183622/discussion-between-dandan-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continued iterations of an endless loop of trial and error I figuered that the way ASP.NET assembles html and styles is not straightforward enough that it can be easily understood for someone who's new to the technology. Hopefully this might change after some time.

So I've stumpled upon this other post ([Cant set proper margin with bootstrap css in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834743/cant-set-proper-margin-with-bootstrap-css-in-mvc)) where somebody else had issues with margins in ASP.NET. This probably isn't the right way of doing things, but for me and for now it works. I've basically avoided adding to my CSS file something like this

> .mb-4 {
>       margin-bottom: 1.5em !important;
>   }

and instead added it to the htmlAttributes collection of the Html helper class for each of my controls, like this:

> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tag1, Model.AvailableTags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", style = "margin-bottom: 1.5em !important;", id = "ddlTag1" })

Answer (score 0):

You use bootstrap 3 and in this version [sapcing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) is not available

So you can imitate the behavior of bootstrap version 4 by creating those class in css

For example I initated the behavior of `mb-4` by add to css `.mb-4 { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }`:

**NOTE!**

- In Razor: use the same code in HTML as you posted but add the css rule
- I use [`em`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) in css only to initate bootstrap but you can use `px` as you want

```css
.mb-4 { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="form-group">
    <label class = "control-label col-md-2" id ="lblSelectedTags">drop down</label> 
    <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class = "form-control mb-4" id = "ddlTag1">
            ddlTag1
            </div>
            <div class = "form-control mb-4" id = "ddlTag2">
            ddlTag2
            </div>
             <div class = "form-control mb-4" id = "ddlTag3">
            ddlTag3
            </div>
           
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion, I've tried to add this to my site.css, to bootstrap.css (really unclear where to add this because I have limited understaning of how the Razor engine bundles things up). Didn't manage to make it work. I'm also confused about this `em`, haven't seen this before. I've tried it with sth like `1.5em` and with sth like `15px`, neither worked. The examples from the Bootstrap4 documentation of course are also not helpful.

Comment: Ok...Let's make order in a mess... Bootstrap 4 decided to use `em` instead `px`  but you can use `px` (I used `em` only to imitate what they did) learn about `em`:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: about Razor do as your code you post and all you have to do is to add the css but maybe to prevent override use :`!important` as here: `.mb-4 { margin-bottom: 1.5em!important; }`

Comment: Well I've pasted the single tag of my rendered html into JS fiddle and added the CSS section and it works. It must be overwritten or otherwise invalid on the entire page

Comment: maybe create a global css to this things and add this global to all pages

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 4 allows for padding and margin tags:

- mt-1 (margin-top) , mb-1 (margin-bottom) , mr-1 (margin-right) , ml-1 ( margin-left) can change the number from 1-5 depending on your needs or replace M for p ( padding)

as for bootstrap 3 you will need to use css

```
.form-group{
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

for example